# Move emails with labels to trash after 1 day fail

Tags: google-apps-script

When I use the script below, sourced from the web, it only works for one (Cam1) of the two labels . The labels within Gmail are associated with the emails and they are older than 1 day.

Why is this script only working as written on one label?

Im new at this so please keep it simple! Thanks

```
function oldEmailDeletion() {
    //Age of email threads that will be deleted (i.e. older_than: # days)
    var daysAgo = 1;
    
    //Expiration date variable
    var expirationDate = new Date();
    
    //Set the older_than date. Any email older than this date will be deleted
    expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate()-daysAgo);

    //Labels associated with emails to be included in deletion
    var labels = [
        'Cam1',
        'Cam2'
    ];

    //Loop through each email label found in the "labels" variable array
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){

        //Retrieve label information based on value in "labels" variable array
        var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labels[i].toString());
    
        //Access all email threads associated with the retrieved label
        var emailThreads = label.getThreads(); //getThreads(###,###) if a specific range of email threads to retrieve
    
        //Loop through each email thread set to "emailThreads" variable
        for(var j = 0; j < emailThreads.length; j++){
        
        //If an email thread is older than the expiration date, then delete
        if(emailThreads[j].getLastMessageDate() < expirationDate){
          emailThreads[j].moveToTrash();
        }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function oldEmailDeletion() {
  var dt=new Date();
  var exp=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-1).valueOf();
  var labels=['Cam1','Cam2'];
  for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
    var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labels[i].toString());
    var emailThreads=label.getThreads(); 
    for(var j=0;j<emailThreads.length;j++){
      if(emailThreads[j].getLastMessageDate().valueOf()<exp){
        emailThreads[j].moveToTrash();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you actually want to delete the messages delete the message older than one day then this approach should work for you.  And you will need to Enable the Gmail API.

```
function oldEmailDeletion() {
  const dt=new Date();
  const exp=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-1).valueOf();
  const labels=['Cam1','Cam2'];
  var idA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
    var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labels[i].toString());
    var emailThreads=label.getThreads(); 
    for(var j=0;j<emailThreads.length;j++){
      if(emailThreads[j].getMessageCount()>0) {
        var msgs=emailThreads[j].getMessages();
        for(var k=0;i<msgs.length;j++) {
          var msg=msgs[k];
          if(new Date(msg.getDate()).valuefOf()<exp) {
            idA.push(msg.getId());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(idA.length>0) {
    var request={"ids":idA};
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
  }
}
```

If you just want to move them to the trash. Then this approach should work for you.

```
function oldEmailTrash() {
  const dt=new Date();
  const exp=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-1).valueOf();
  const labels=['Cam1','Cam2'];
  var idA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
    var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labels[i].toString());
    var emailThreads=label.getThreads(); 
    for(var j=0;j<emailThreads.length;j++){
      if(emailThreads[j].getMessageCount()>0) {
        var msgs=emailThreads[j].getMessages();
        for(var k=0;i<msgs.length;j++) {
          var msg=msgs[k];
          if(new Date(msg.getDate()).valueOf()<exp) {
            idA.push(msg.getId());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(idA.length>0) {
    idA.forEach(function(msg){msg.moveToTrash();});
  }
}
```

Comment: Better... That moved some of the emails from both labels >1 day old to the trash but left others.  Those that were not moved have the correct label applied to them.  Could this be an issue with the way dates are handled in the script?

Comment: I changed the expiration date a little so that it's time is midnight...The start of day. You might want to do it to the message date as well if there is an element of time to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the script edits are not deleting any of the labeled e-mails including those older than 24 hours.  Odd. Maybe this is more complex than I thought!

Comment: if the threads are continuing to receive emails then they will never be deleted because were using getLastMessageDate();  You code was setup to delete threads not messages.

Comment: Maybe I know less than I think... I have 'Conversation View' off so my inbox is filled with individual e-mails.  My intention is to clear all individual e-mails with a labels after 1 day.  Are you saying the script in my initial post is not a good starting point to do this?  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some debugging should be expected for either approach since I don't want to unleash that sort thing on my account and hence the code was not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cooper.  I tried for days but lacked the skills to debug your scripts. I found and modified the script below and it works.

First I created a new filter in gmail that labeled all cam emails 'Clean' then set the script below on a trigger. This was the only way I was able to achieve my goal.

Thanks again!

```
function gmailCleaningRobot() {
  
  var delayDays = 1; // will only impact emails more than 24h old
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays); // what was the date at that time?
  
  // creating an array containing all the search strings matching the emails we want to be treated automatically
  var searches = [
    'label:Clean older_than:1d' //with label clean and older than 1d
    //'"is now available on Spotify" from:spotify is:unread', // Spotify new album notification
    //'YOUR NEW SEARCH STRING HERE', // any other search string
    //'YOUR NEW SEARCH STRING HERE', // any other search string
    //'YOUR NEW SEARCH STRING HERE', // any other search string
    //'YOUR NEW SEARCH STRING HERE' // any other search string
    ];
  
  // creating an array containing all the threads matching the searches above
  var threads = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
    var tmp_threads = GmailApp.search(searches[i], 0, 500); // I limit the search to 500 results but you can adjust this one
    var threads = threads.concat(tmp_threads);
  }
  
  // we archive all the threads if they're older than the time limit we set in delayDays
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
    {
      threads[i].moveToTrash();
    }
  }
}
```